# Add a default value in migration in Vapor

Tags: swift, vapor, vapor-fluent

How do I add a default value for a non-optional field in a fluent migration?
I currently have this error:

```
⚠️ PostgreSQL Error: column "firstName" contains null values
```

my only options are

```
public func field<T>(for key: KeyPath<Self.Model, T>, isIdentifier: Bool? = nil)
public func field<T>(for key: KeyPath<Self.Model, T>, type: Self.Model.Database.SchemaFieldType)
```

**EDIT:** Thanks to Tim's answer, the solution is:

```
static func prepare(on conn: PostgreSQLConnection) -> Future<Void> {
        return Database.update(User.self, on: conn) { builder in
            builder.field(for: \User.firstName, type: .text, .default(.literal("")))
        }
    }
```

Comment: I believe that it is available only through raw query at the moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is another option that you haven't seen:

```swift
static func prepare(on connection: PostgreSQLConnection) -> Future<Void> {
  return Database.update(Event.self, on: connection) { builder in
    builder.field(for: \Event.isPrivate, type: .boolean, .default(.literal(.boolean(.false))))
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error `PostgreSQL Error: column "created_at" of relation "experiments" already exists` when using this to add a default value.

Answer (score 13):

Just in case someone get here and is trying to do it in Vapor 4:

```
func prepare(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
    let defaultValue = SQLColumnConstraintAlgorithm.default(false)
    return database.schema(“event”)
        .field(“is_private”, .bool, .sql(defaultValue))
        .update()
}
```

Comment: or simply `.sql(.default(false))`